# Errors from Command line, but successful execution of A SERVLET from webpage using the URL. THANKS

Tags: tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea

```
  package com.bisht.demos;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;

@WebServlet(name = "ShowRequestHeaders")
public class ShowRequestHeaders extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        out.println("<!Doctype HTML>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<title>Showing all Request Headers</title>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>All Request Headers </h1>");

        out.println("<p><b>Request Method:</b>"+request.getMethod());
        out.println("<p><b>Request URRL :</b>"+request.getRequestURL());
        out.println("<p><b>Request Protocol:<b>"+request.getProtocol());


        Enumeration<String> headerNames=request.getHeaderNames();
        while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()){
            String headerName=headerNames.nextElement();
            out.println("<p><b>"+headerName+":</b>"+request.getHeader(headerName)+"</p>");
        }

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

When i run this code on Web browser with the proper URL i get to see the successful execution of web page which is this :-- [http://localhost:8080/ShowRequestHeaders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbVwY.jpg)

But When i try to execute the servlet program in command line, it shows me errors! Which is this over here : - [Command line image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAtpT.jpg)

**MANY THANKS IN ADVANCE !**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.165]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Akash\IdeaProjects\yoyo\src\com\bisht\demos>set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
\bin

C:\Users\Akash\IdeaProjects\yoyo\src\com\bisht\demos>javac SetStatusDemo.java
SetStatusDemo.java:3: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
                    ^
SetStatusDemo.java:4: error: package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
                               ^
SetStatusDemo.java:5: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
                         ^
SetStatusDemo.java:6: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
                         ^
SetStatusDemo.java:7: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
                         ^
SetStatusDemo.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
public class SetStatusDemo extends HttpServlet {
                                   ^
  symbol: class HttpServlet
SetStatusDemo.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
@WebServlet(name = "SetStatusDemo")
 ^
  symbol: class WebServlet
SetStatusDemo.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Servl
etException, IOException {
                          ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
  location: class SetStatusDemo
SetStatusDemo.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Servl
etException, IOException {
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
  location: class SetStatusDemo
SetStatusDemo.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Servl
etException, IOException {
                                                                                           ^
  symbol:   class ServletException
  location: class SetStatusDemo
SetStatusDemo.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Servle
tException, IOException {
                         ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
  location: class SetStatusDemo
SetStatusDemo.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Servle
tException, IOException {
                                                     ^
  symbol:   class HttpServletResponse
  location: class SetStatusDemo
SetStatusDemo.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Servle
tException, IOException {
                                                                                          ^
  symbol:   class ServletException
  location: class SetStatusDemo
SetStatusDemo.java:18: error: cannot f
ind symbol
        response.setStatus(HttpServlet
Response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable HttpServletResponse
  location: class SetStatusDemo
14 errors

C:\Users\Akash\IdeaProjects\yoyo\src\com\bisht\demos>
```

MANY THANKS IN ADVANCE !

Comment: you're missing the libraries needed for a java servlet. This would have been done automatically if you setup the project correctly.

Comment: I think i need to re- setup my project. Thanks you so much Jonathan Laliberte